# Text Based Video Game Project

Tags: python, text

I am new to Python and am struggling to complete a project for my university. We are supposed to write a linear, text-based however I am struggling to figure out why I can't seem to enter one of the rooms. Here is the code that I have thus far:

```
rooms = {
    'Meeting Room': {'North': 'Main Storage', 'East': 'Kitchen'},
    'Main Storage': {'North': 'Break room', 'East': 'Janitorial Closet', 'South': 'Meeting Room', 'West': 'Generator Room'},
    'Generator Room': {'East': 'Main Storage', 'North': 'Storage Closet'},
    'Break Room': {'South': 'Main Storage', 'West': 'Dirty Bathroom'},
    'Dirty Bathroom': {'East': 'Break Room'},
    'Storage Closet': {'South': 'Generator Room'},
    'Janitorial Closet': {'West': 'Main Storage'}
}
items = {
    'Meeting Room': 'Nothing of interest, please proceed further',
    'Main Storage': 'Kenny',
    'Generator Room': 'Alex',
    'Break Room': 'Jacquees',
    'Kitchen': 'Guard',
    'Dirty Bathroom': 'Evgeny',
    'Janitorial Closet': 'Ramirez',
    'Storage Closet': 'Miguel'

}
state = 'Meeting Room'
inventory = []


# function
def get_new_state(state, direction):
    new_state = state  # declaring
    for i in rooms:  # loop
        if i == state:  # if
            if direction in rooms[i]:  # if
                new_state = rooms[i][direction]  # assigning new_state

    return new_state  # return


while 1:  # gameplay loop
    print('You are in the ', state)  # printing state
    if state == 'Kitchen':
        print('Battling with the guard', end='')
        for i in range(50):
            for j in range(1000000):
                pass
            print(".", end='', flush=True)
        print()
        if len(inventory) == 6:
            print('You escaped - nice!')
        else:
            print('Sorry, you lost - gather all of your friends next time')
        break

    print('Available to you in this room is', items[state])
    print('You currently have', inventory)
    direction = input('Enter item you want OR direction to go OR exit to give up: ')  # asking user
    if direction.lower() == items[state].lower():
        if items[state] not in inventory:
            inventory.append(items[state])
        continue
    direction = direction.capitalize()  # making first character capital remaining lower
    if direction == 'Exit':  # if
        exit(0)  # exit function
    if direction == 'East' or direction == 'West' or direction == 'North' or direction == 'South':  # if
        new_state = get_new_state(state, direction)  # calling function
        if new_state == state:  # if
            print('Stop bumping into walls!')  # print
        else:
            state = new_state  # changing state value to new_state
    else:
        print('Invalid direction!!')  # print
```

Here is what I get when I run the code:

Enter item you want OR direction to go OR exit to give up: North
You are in the  Main Storage
Available to you in this room is Kenny
You currently have []
Enter item you want OR direction to go OR exit to give up: North
You are in the  Break room
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/dmitrysenyk/PycharmProjects/TextBasedGameV2/main.py", line 51, in 
print('Available to you in this room is', items[state])
KeyError: 'Break room'

Process finished with exit code 1

I don't understand why I'm having problems with the 'Break Room,' and I gotta move to Europe in a week so I, unfortunately, do not have as much time as I would like to figure out where I went wrong. Any input would be greatly appreciated, thank you guys in advance!

Comment: "Break room" is not the same as "Break Room". Capitalization matters.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response! I'm ashamed to admit that I have spent a good bit of time trying to figure out what was wrong and still failed to notice the capitalization error in the dictionary. Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's one of those things that just comes with time and practice--you learn what the common errors you make are and what each error message probably means. Next time this happens, you'll be able to fix it faster! Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the key from Break room to Break Room (notice the capitalization)

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the help!